# Crash when Adding a WebView to a Multiview Tab Bar App

Tags: uiviewcontroller, webview

I am new to this and working thru a "teach yourself book". I have two questions. How to trouble-shoot this in the future and how to get the darn thing to work now.

I have a simple three Tab Bar app that points to three UIViewController. The three views work fine until I add a Webview to one of the XIBs. As soon as I bring up the view with the WebView included in the simulator, I am kicked out of the App.

The Debugger console says"'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bannerView.'"  I don't know what that means.

.h file  code....

@interface ConvNavController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *bannerView;
}
-(IBAction)loadbannerView:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *bannerView;

=========
.m file code
-(IBAction)loadbannerView:(id)sender{

```
NSURL *bannerURL; 
NSString *bannerURLString;

bannerURLString=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.tak2000.com/banner_test.html"];
bannerURL =[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:bannerURLString];  
[bannerView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:bannerURL]];   

[bannerURL release];
[bannerURLString release];
```

}

## I used a simple button connected to loadbannerView.

Webview code worked great in a simple one view example. Why is it dying when I use it in multi UIViewController app?  BTW: I used the "Windows Based App" template as a starting point.  I also ensured the Class Identity was UIWebView.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

bannerView is a property, so it should be

```
[self.bannerView loadRequest ....]
```

and make sure in interface builder that you've connected your `UIWebView` to the `bannerView` outlet.

Comment: Thanks Jgubman.  However no joy.  [self.bannerView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:bannerURL]];
And I checked the Outlet connection

Comment: Thanks again Jgubman....I rebuilt the project from scratch (for the second time) and it worked.   Obviously it was operator error.